# How to deal with a mix of UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 characters in Python?

Tags: unicode, python-2.7, character-encoding, python-unicode

I have a set of documents that appear to contain characters encoded in both UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1.  I'd like them to be just UTF-8 encoded.

When I take a document and decode it to UTF-8 using `doc.decode('utf-8')` I end up with some unicode escape sequences like `\u2022`, but I also have a lot of characters like `\xa0` that I believe are ISO-8859-1.  I'd like to convert those to their unicode equivalents so everything lives happily together.  Is this possible?  I'm using Python 2.74.

One thing I've done is this:

```
decoded_doc = doc.decode('utf-8')
new_doc = decoded_doc.replace(u'\xa0',u' ')
```

but there are other strange characters like `\xb7` -- I want to get them all in one fell swoop.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "UTF-8 character". UTF-8 is an *encoding*.

Comment: U+00A0 is NO-BREAK SPACE; U+00B7 is MIDDLE DOT. These are ordinary Unicode characters: there's no need to try to convert them to "Unicode equivalents".

Comment: @Gareth Rees I see... so just because the escape sequence doesn't start with `\u` doesn't mean that these aren't unicode?

Comment: That's right, there are several ways to write the same character: `u'\xa0' == u'\u00A0' == u'\200'`

Comment: If you successfully decode from `utf-8` without raising an exception, you probably had valid `utf-8` to begin with. It's possible that your source has already messed up the characters before it was encoded into `utf-8` but that's a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

Characters are not exclusive property of an encoding, you can't say `a` is "an UTF-8 character" while `b` is a "ASCII character" in the sense and context that implies that no other encodings are capable of representing those characters.

If your file decodes as UTF-8 without error, it was valid UTF-8. It cannot have been a "mix of UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1".

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to the other question you're implicitly asking:

If you want the character U+00A0, which is visually indistinguishable from a space, to be converted to a space, along with many other conversions of that sort, this is called NFKC normalization. You can accomplish it with `unicodedata.normalize`:

```
import unicodedata
new_doc = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', decoded_doc)
```